# Curves extends beyond the axis limits when plotting on added layers

Tags: pgfplots, legend, axis, layers, pgflayers

I have encountered some problem while I was trying to change curves displaying order and at the same time maintaining the legend entries order.

The curves order was changed as expected, however, they extended beyond the axis limits.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{A}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{B}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{C}
    \pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/layers/my layers/.define layer set={main,A,B,C}{}}
    
    \begin{axis}[xmax=9,ymin=0,set layers=my layers]
        \addplot[line width=3pt,red,on layer=A] coordinates {(0,10) (10,0)};
        \addplot[line width=3pt,green,on layer=C] coordinates {(0,9) (10,1)};
        \addplot[line width=3pt,blue,on layer=B] coordinates {(0,8) (10,2)};
        \legend{case 1,case 2,case 3}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not changing the axis limits or the curves limits

Comment: I am using 'xmax' and 'ymin' to set the axis limits. It works when the curves are drawn in a regular manner, but not in the above MWE. As for modifying the curves, in the original problem I am reading the curves from a data file and I don' t want to modify it.

Comment: In the provided example if you set `\begin{axis}[xmax=11,ymin=-1,set layers=my layers]` the curves will be inside the limits

Comment: Yes, but this is not what I want. I want to hide the curve's points with x>9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to add `clip mode=individual` to the `axis` options.
(Besides that the `\pgfdeclarelayer` commands are superfluous because they are called by `.define layer set` anyway.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        /pgfplots/layers/my layers/.define layer set={main,A,B,C}{},
    }
    \begin{axis}[
        set layers=my layers,
        xmax=9,
        ymin=0,
        clip mode=individual,
    ]
        \addplot [line width=3pt,red,  on layer=A] coordinates {(0,10) (10,0)};
        \addplot [line width=3pt,green,on layer=C] coordinates {(0,9) (10,1)};
        \addplot [line width=3pt,blue, on layer=B] coordinates {(0,8) (10,2)};
        \legend{case 1,case 2,case 3}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Superb. Thanks!